# Custom Interactive UI Boxes in Google Apps Script

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I know this question has somewhat been asked before, but I could not find a definitive answer for it.

I am attempting to make an interactive, custom-designed UI menu for a google doc add-on. I would like to be able to code in items such as pull-down menus or checkboxes. Are these possibilities with this discontinuation of the UI Service? And if so, how would I go about coding this? Even a link to a place that might have suggestions would be a help. Thanks!

Comment: Sidebars use html. So go nuts. This is not a place to ask for html tutorials

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the UI Service has been deprecated and replaced by HtmlService. HtmlService let's you build a complete UI with HTML, CSS and client side Javascript, so you can make the UI as simple or complex as you like.

HtmlService intefaces can be rendered in sidebars or in popup dialogs, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

See the HtmlService documentation here, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/